# OData WCF Services throw 500 silently, how can I debug it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, odata

What are possible ways I could debug OData WCF Data services ?

I have this data services class,

```
public class ExampleDataServices : EntityFrameworkDataService<ExampleContext>
```

When I add this method to it,

```
    [QueryInterceptor("MyEntities")]
    public Expression<Func<MyEntity, Boolean>> OnQueryMyEntities()
    {
        return null;
    }
```

I am not even able to get `$metadata` it returns 500,

**What I really want ?**

I want WCF data services to tell me where it's breaking, at the moment I only get 500 for any sort of error.

I added above error by purpose so please only answer above question, thank you.